# New UNO, BLINK not working

Tags: arduino-uno

Finally got around to playing with my uno today for the first time. ( It's a branded sunfounder UNO R3)

First project. Simple blink. Using arduino 1.6.3, Windows 8.1 It is hooked up correctly.

```
void setup() {
   // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
   pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
   digitalWrite(9, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
   delay(10000);              // wait for a second
   digitalWrite(9, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
   delay(10000);              // wait for a second
}
```

What I get is a fast blinking LED. I've tried multiple values and it doesn't change. No error on upload.
I've commented out everything except the digitalWrite(9, HIGH); and I get a fast blink.

I tried:

```
void loop() {
   digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   delay(5000);
   digitalWrite(9, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
}
```

And I get nothing, it doesn't even turn on.

Same if I remove the first digitalWrite();

So, I'm already a little lost here. I did a but of google searching tried adding a serial 9600 line, and a few other things. Nada.

Comment: For your second snippet, you will never be able to see a single blink, that's because a second `delay(5000)` misses, in the end of the main loop. If you have an oscilloscope, or anything that can measure a frequency, check if the embedded quartz beats at 16MHz

Comment: No oscilloscope, or anything else to check frequency.  This is my first attempt playing with hardware like this but even if it was at 16MHz wouldn't the blink speed still change?  I tried many different values in there and it never changed.

Comment: Do you have and LED (and resistor) connected to digital pin 9 or is it the on board LED (which is on digital pin 13) you are observing ?

Comment: I've tried pin 9 with resister and I've tried 13.  Same result with both.  Same fast blink that doesn't change no matter what delay value ( I've tried up to 100000).  I tried a previous version of the arduino IDE also. Same thing.

Comment: Have you corrected the code? You must change the pin state to LOW, then delay, HIGH and again a delay! Also, mind that the internal led is on pin 13!

Comment: @Spirine Corrected?  The original code is there, and yes I was changing to the correct pin.    There isn't much to this really its like 4 lines.  Should work.

Comment: What you've written in the second code (starting with `void loop...`) will never work: you put off the LED, then you wait 5 seconds, then you put on the LED, and the program goes to the beginning of the loop, which take circa 100 nanoseconds, you put off the LED, etc. So, if you're able to see a blink of a few nanoseconds, yes, your code will work.

Comment: That was only to test nothing else.  I'm just trying to get the original code to work.

Comment: Try a different sketch to check the internal timers are running ok e.g unsigned long time;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.print("Time: ");
  time = millis();
  //prints time since program started
  Serial.println(time);
  // wait a second so as not to send massive amounts of data
  delay(1000);
}

Comment: Ok did that.  All I get is Time: 0 repeating over and over in the serial monitor. Also, did not seem to pause for a second.

Comment: Sunfounder thinks it's a bad board.  Probably going to return it and buy  a real arduino and not a clone.

Comment: it may just be the fuses aren't set correctly. You can correct this by using the IDE to 'Burn Bootloader' making sure the correct board (Uno in your case) is selected first. Double check the board labelling as I've found some supposed 'Uno' boards from eBay were in fact Duemilanove's

Comment: Ok, tried that.  Got a bunch of "Not in sync" errors.  Not sure if I did it right though.  Connected usb, chose the right board, then burn bootloader.  Think I'm just going to cut my losses and get a working board.

Comment: You can sometimes get round that problem by manually resetting the board (using the reset button) and releasing the reset button at the correct time whilst attempting to 'Burn Bootloader', can take a few goes to get the timing right. Failing that you can add a couple of components to temporarily disable the auto reset, which normally occurs when you upload a sketch. Use a 120 ohm resistance connected between the RESET pin of Arduino and +5 V, and a 10µF capacitor connected with the positive pole to the RESET of Arduino and negative to GND.

Comment: What should I be choosing under "programmer" when I'm doing this?  I just left it on the default of AVR ISP.

Comment: this is nonsense, you have initialized pin 9 as output and expecting pin 13 to do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defective board.  Thanks to @br1an for the milli idea.  New board in the way,  not a clone.

Comment: it's @Bra1n but you're welcome anyway

Comment: Sorry for the typo, thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

*Added as new answer because comments limit was reached*
Doesn't really matter which programmer you set because in this instance you're not actually burning the bootloader just setting the fuses (to those already stored in boards.txt for the Uno) but 'Using Arduino as ISP' is the nearest to what you're doing